# Multithreaded programs in smt mode running only one thread gem5

Tags: multithreading, gem5

Does gem5 support running Multithreaded programs fully in smt mode?
I've been trying to run PARSEC benchmarks. However, the stats show execution of only one thread.

I ran this command:

```
./build/ALPHA_FS/gem5.opt --debug-flag=O3CPUAll configs/example/fs.py --cpu-type=DerivO3CPU --smt --kernel=$M5_PATH/binaries/vmlinux_2.6.27-gcc_4.3.4 --caches --script=runscript.rcS
```

The disk image is from http://www.cs.utexas.edu/~parsec_m5/. (parsec2.1)

> gem5 version: a3d2a9ec92ad4406ccf51ff45a4a1d2aa16eaa69

Is there something I am missing?